# Symfony, Google charts and JQuery: plotting Json data on google charts

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, symfony, google-visualization

I am trying to plot JSON fetched data to my google charts graph. the controller that is passing data is:

```
$em = $this->get("doctrine")->getManager();
        $this->get("doctrine")->getManager();
        $conn       = $em->getConnection();
        $sql        = "SELECT MONTH(s.timestamp) as mon, SUM(s.amt) as total FROM sales s GROUP BY MONTH(s.timestamp) ORDER BY MONTH(s.timestamp)";
        $stmt       = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();

        $all_rows   = $stmt->fetchAll();

        return new JsonResponse($all_rows);
```

output from controller:

> [{"mon":"4","total":"300"},{"mon":"5","total":"4000"}]

and it is giving the expected output the following is the script for google charts is:

```
        function abc() {
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages': ['bar']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
        var JsonData = $.ajax({
            url: "/admin/graph/sales",
            dataType: "json",
            async: false
        }).responseText;
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(JsonData);
        var options = {
            chart: {
                title: 'Total Sales developed into system'
            }
        };

        var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
}
abc();
```

But I can see a notice being displayed on the screen:

> Invalid data table format: must have at least 2 columns.

Controller passes 2 rows, I think there is a minor change in either of them.

Comment: see examples under the [DataTable Class](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable) __Constructor__ section for valid data format -- need to provide column headings and valid row cells take the format `{v: 'value', f: 'formatted value'}`

Comment: didn't quite understood how to do it!